# Do you get bonus points for unused items in Centipede?

Tags: centipede

Do you get bonus points for unused items such as weapons and shields in 1998 PC version of Centipede? The reason I ask is because I'm trying to beat my old hi-scores on maps. If you do get bonus points for unused items then how many points do you get for *each* of the items? The only thing I know is that you don't get bonus points for unused shields. Any ideas? Links to back your answers would be beneficial.

Comment: Any reason for your rollback? The edit looked like an improvement to me.